# calling function inside nested class

Tags: python-3.x, class, nested, self-reference

I would like to call functions defined in a class (1) from a nested class (2) (class 2 defined in the class 1). something similar to the code below:

```
class firstclass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #some code and functions...
    def afunction(self):
        #some code
    class nestedclass(tkinter.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            #some code
        def anotherfunction(self):
            #here I would like to call a function from the class firstclass from a button
            self.abutton = tkinter.Button(self.parent, text = "blabla", command = firstclass.afunction)
            self.abutton.grid(row = 0, column = 1,columnspan=1)
```

However I keep getting an error missing required positional argument self. how to give it this argument in the command option?

or any advice how to work around this issue?
thanks a lot in advance for all input

Comment: why are you nesting classes, exactly? Despite that, nesting or not, `afunction` is a method of the class `firstclass`, therefore you should call it via an instance of that class `firstclass().afunction`.

Comment: Replace firstclass.afunction to parent.afunction